# Find value of P and E(x)

Tags: probability, random-variables

The random variable $X$ takes on the values $1$, $2$, or $3$ with probabilities
$$\frac{2+5P}{5}, \frac{1+3P}{5} , \frac{1.5+2P}{5}$$, respectively.

What is the  value of $P$ and $E(x)$?

Comment: did you try anything at all?

Comment: Be sure and let us know what you've done so far. This website is not a solution guide for your homework. You have to let us know if you don't understand what to do or what you've attempted so far.

Comment: Yeah you are right sir. I made P(X=1)=(2+5P)/5.  ,P(X=2)=(1+3P)/5 and P(X=3)=(1.5+2P)/5.            And Expectation E(x)=xp(x) then how should i proceed furthur...And am i going right ?

Comment: The first part is the restatement of the assignment. The second part is wrong: $E[X]$ is just a real number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One property of a discrete random variable is that the probabilies add up to one. In your case

$$\sum_{x=1}^3 P(X=x)=1$$

$P(X=1)+P(X=2)+P(X=3)=1$

$\frac{2+5P}{5}+ \frac{1+3P}{5} + \frac{1.5+2P}{5}=1$

$2+5P+1+3P+1.5+2P=5$

Solve for $P$. After you have evaluated the value for $P$ you can calculate $P(X=x)$ for every single value of $x$.

Then the expected value is

$$E(X)=\sum_{x=1}^3x\cdot P(X=x)$$